# JPA Named Query for sql 'is not true'

Tags: hibernate, jpa, named-query

I am using JPA with hibernate and named query and I need have a named query like this:

```
findInstancesByCol1NotEquals(Boolean.TRUE)
```

This generates sql like this:

```
select * from instance where col1 <> true;
```

But I have entries with null values that did not came in the query results.

So what I really need is a named query that generates sql like the following:

```
select * from instance where col1 is not true;
```

I already try 'findInstancessByCol1IsNot' but it does not work.

Anyone knows how I can get what I need?

Comment: Why not just  `findByCol1False()`.

Comment: Because I want the query to return both the false and null values

Comment: Are you find any decision for your problem?

Comment: No, I became to be sure that that column has no null values... :(

Comment: I have a similar issue. I create string query statement and need is not <boolean value>. Does not work in JPQL